# Using Promises in AngularJS Views

Tags: view, angularjs, promise

Mark Dalgleish wrote a [nice little article](http://markdalgleish.com/2013/06/using-promises-in-angularjs-views/) about how to use promises in AngularJS views.
Some people asked questions about this in the comments, but Mark didn't answer them (yet). Because I'm asking me the same question, I will ask on StackOverflow instead to get an answer:

1. If you use promises in views, how do I handle "loading"/"waiting" indication, because they are async? Does a promise have something like a "resolved" or "withinRequest" property?
2. How do I handle errors? Normally they would arise in the second callback, but if I use a promise directly in the view I don't handle this case. Is there another way?

Thank you.

Comment: just read about $q on angular official docs and your above two questions will be answered

Comment: It doesn't seem that #rtfm helps here, because I don't want to use the promise programmatically but from within the view as described in the question/article. That doesn't seem to be part of the docs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDIT: as of angular v1.2 the [resolution of promise in views is not activated by default](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#templates-no-longer-automatically-unwrap-promises).

The automatic resolution of promises in a view looks like a handy tool at first but it has number of limitations that need to be understood and evaluated carefully. The biggest issue with this approach is that it is AngularJS who will add callbacks to a promise and we've got little control over it.

Answering your questions:

1) As indicated, it is ultimately AngularJS who will add a success / error callbacks so we don't have much control here. What you could do is to wrap the original promise into a custom one that would track resolution. But this kind of deft the whole purpose of saving few keystrokes. And no, there is no things like 'resolved'. In short - there is no universal mechanism for tracking progress that would work for all promises. If your promises are `$http`-based you might use interceptors or `pendingRequests` property to track request in progress.

2) You can't. Once again, it is AngularJS that adds a handler inside the `$parse` service and it looks like this: `promise.then(function(val) { promise.$$v = val; });` (see code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/parse.js#L803)). You can see that only a success callback are added so all the failures are going to be silently ignored.

Those are not the only limitations of the automatic promise resolution in the view. The other problem is that promises returned by a function won't be resolved correctly. For example, if you would rewrite an example like so:

```
myModule.controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope, HelloWorld) {

  $scope.messages = function() {
    return HelloWorld.getMessages();
  }
});
```

and try to use the following markup:

```
<li ng-repeat="message in messages()"></li>
```

things would work as expected, which might come as a surprise.

In short: while the automatic resolution of promises might seem like a handy shortcut it has number of limitations and non-obvious behaviors. Evaluate those carefully and decide if saving few keystrokes are worth it.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer.

Comment: "promises returned by a function won't be resolved correctly", but "things would work as expected" - shouldn't this be "wouldn't"? ;)